# On click of two different radio button how to hide and show same div in angularjs, without using any function?

Tags: html, angularjs

> These are my Radio Buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="qualitative" value="qualitative1" ng-model="showDiv">Show
<input type="radio" name="qualitative" value="qualitative2" ng-model="hideDiv">Hide
```

> This is the div to be hide and show:

```
<div id="mark_me_visible">
   <h1>I am Visible</h1> 
</div>
```

Please help me with this
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="radio" name="qualitative" value="show" ng-model="showDiv">Show
<input type="radio" name="qualitative" value="hide" ng-model="showDiv">Hide

<div id="mark_me_visible" ng-show="showDiv === 'show'">
   <h1>I am Visible</h1> 
</div>
```

and in controller:

```
$scope.showDiv = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" name="qualitative" value="qualitative1" ng-model="showDiv" ng-click="show()">Show
<input type="radio" name="qualitative" value="qualitative2" ng-model="hideDiv" ng-click="hide()">Hide
```

In the controller

```
$scope.show = function(){
   $scope.show_div = true
  }
$scope.hide = function(){
   $scope.show_div = false
  }
```

In the div

```
<div id="mark_me_visible" ng-if=!show_div>
  <h1>I am Visible</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: i don't want functions, because there are many such questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Since we are using angularjs you have to define module and controller as I have done below.

```js
var app = angular.module('IApp', []);

app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {

});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="IApp" ng-controller="formCtrl">
  <input type="radio" name="qualitative" ng-init="showDiv=true" checked="true" ng-click="showDiv = !showDiv">Show
  <input type="radio" name="qualitative" ng-init="showDiv=true" ng-click="showDiv = !showDiv">Hide
  <div id="Div1" ng-model="showDiv" ng-init="showDiv=true" ng-show="showDiv">
    <h1>I am Visible {{showDiv}}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```